# Error 10001st prime number in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, primes

My code:

```
import java.util.*

fun checkPrime(n : Int): Boolean{
    val z = n/2
    var stop = false
    if(n == 0 || n == 1){
        stop = true
        return false
    }
    for(i in 2..z){
        if(n % i == 0){
            stop = true
            return false
            break
        }
    }
    return !stop
}

fun main(args : Array<String>){
    var primes = ArrayList<Int>()
    //The "500000" can be replaced with any number so you get at least 100001 primes
    for(i in 2..500000){
        if(checkPrime(i)){
            primes.add(i)
        }
    }
    println("Finished")
    println("Size of Array: ${primes.size}")
    println("10001st Prime: ${primes.get(index = 10001)}")
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin so this probably looks horrible to you. When I run it, I get 104759, which is wrong. Where is the error here? Is my prime checking function incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: your program is correct, but you are checking the 10002nd prime (because indexing starts with 0) which is indeed 104759

Comment: additionally, your z should be square root of n, not `n/2`; also there is no point in using stop variable because function exists on return statement

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could use Java's built in Prime Number checker and Kotlin's infinite sequences generated by buildSequence.

Ensure that you use take() to select how many elements you want to extract.

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.buildSequence

fun primes() = buildSequence {
    var n = 1
    while (true){
        if (BigInteger("$n").isProbablePrime(1)){
            yield(n)
        }
        n++
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(primes().take(10001).last())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Prime numbers are of the form 6f ± 1, excluding 2 and 3 where f is any integer

```
fun isPrime(number: Int) : Boolean 
{

   if (number <= 1)
   {
      return false;
   }   

   // The check for the number 2 and 3
   if (number <= 3)
   {
      return true;
   }

   if (number%2 == 0 || number%3 == 0)
   {
      return false;
   }

   for (i in 5..number/2 step 6)
   {

      if (number%i == 0 || number%(i+2) == 0)
      {
         return false;
      }   
   }
   return true;
}
```

Time Complexity of the solution: O(sqrt(n))